# OpenSSL "error reading input file" and "bad magic number"

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to encrypt a simple string "Hello world." with the OpenSSL command line tool. I've tried both encrypting using both base64 and binary. But I'm getting some unhelpful errors.

```
$ "Hello world." > plain.txt
$ openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -e -base64 -in plain.txt > enc.txt
enter aes-128-ecb encryption password:
Verifying - enter aes-128-ecb encryption password:
$ cat enc.txt
U2FsdGVkX18ZoAY34fL2aMO0Bu5AJnewemhfiBmSL1IJujqOtpJm7V0C+Tt83egJ
$ openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -d -base64 -in enc.txt > out.txt
enter aes-128-ecb decryption password:
error reading input file
```

Then I try binary

```
$ "Hello world." > plain.txt
$ openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -e -in plain.txt > enc.bin
enter aes-128-ecb encryption password:
Verifying - enter aes-128-ecb encryption password:
$ openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -d -in enc.bin > out.txt 
enter aes-128-ecb decryption password:
bad magic number
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark, I don't see anything wrong with your commands.  They all worked fine on my system.  So the problem must be somewhere else.

I'd recommend trying a different installation/version of OpenSSL, or a different system.

Comment: Yeah I tried it on Ubuntu and it worked. It's broken on my Windows 7 system. The version is the openssl which is packaged with git.

Comment: Mark, another Windows version of OpenSSL you can try is at [slproweb.com](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe your commands are not wrong, because I met the same problem these days. The TXT file could not change into the second line automatically, thus, you need to input an "**Enter**" at the end of the cipher text and save the text. Then, you can input your command again.

> $ openssl enc -des -d -base64 -in atxt > a2.txt
>
> enter des-cbc decryption password:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1Ogh.png)