# OpenSSL: Bad magic number using command line tool

Tags: windows, openssl

For background, I am working through the [Matasano Crypto Challenges](https://cryptopals.com/). One of the problems (Set1, Challenge 7) is to decrypt an AES-128 ECB mode [file](https://cryptopals.com/static/challenge-data/7.txt) with a given key, YELLOW SUBMARINE.

The file is base64 encoded and I can decrypt the file in Python but I cannot using the Windows 10 `openssl` command line tool.

The command I am running is:

`openssl aes-128-ecb -d -a -in 7.txt -pass pass:"YELLOW SUBMARINE"`

When I run this I am told that I have a `bad magic number`.

Does anyone have an idea of why I am getting this error?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I'm not sure if the question is a programming/development question but isn't `openssl` a common tool used by programmers? I see that there is a fine line but I am asking this in the same spirit as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161716/bad-magic-number-error-when-trying-to-decrypt-file-in-openssl) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514495/openssl-error-reading-input-file-and-bad-magic-number?rq=1).

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the `-pass` option doesn't like the space in the passphrase.

You can use the option `-K` with the hexadecimal key like this:

```
openssl aes-128-ecb -d -a -K 59454c4c4f57205355424d4152494e45 -in 7.txt
```

Or use the passphrase directly with this command:

```
openssl aes-128-ecb -d -a -in 7.txt -K  $(echo -n "YELLOW SUBMARINE" | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X"')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness: encrypting with -a params ( Perform base64 encoding/decoding (alias -base64) ) and decrypting without it ( or vice-versa ), bad magic number given.